# Do we need SharePoint when using project online

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-online

Do we really need SharePoint online even after we setup project online, because AFAIK project online have capabilities of SharePoint with some extra features like resource management etc...

I am in a dilemma, what happens if i just buy project online without SharePoint online?? Will I still be able to do all the customization as in SharePoint, I never really tried this u know.

Here are my requirements:

1. Creating a web app with all the sites.
2. Setup custom Login.
3. Create necessary libraries/Lists etc...

Please can anyone explain?

Comment: Project Online is built over SharePoint Online.. so if you purchase a plan for Project Online you will get SharePoint Online by default

Comment: Thanks @dsouzajoel22 , AFAIK we have to create seperate site to implement Resource Allocation as PWA, Can we use Resource Allocation directly in Sharepoint Site rather than creating it seperately in Project Web Application.

Comment: Resource Allocation is part of PWA only. We cant do it directly in SharePoint.